# Simple calculation using jQuery

Tags: jquery

HI freinds I developing a Simple calculator in which when user selects any product by check the checkbox then the price of the selected product will be displayed in `.count` `<td>`there are four product and each product has its own checkhox and `.count` class.

Now the main thing I want when user select any of product and increase its quantity then plus all the amount and display in `.countTotal`.

As per my code its showing `NaN`

Please help me

You can se my code below or you can also check **[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cccEF/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="brochure"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" >
  <tr>
    <td width="21%" align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="50" class="" name="radio"> 
    Rs. 50 </td>
    <td width="29%" align="center"><img src="images/thumb_brochure_singlepage_back.jpg" alt=" "></td>
    <td width="10%" align="center"><label for=" "></label>
      <input name=" 2" type="text" class="qty" id=" " maxlength="2"></td>
    <td width="40%" align="center" class="count">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="75" class="" name="radio5">
Rs. 75 </td>
    <td align="center"><img src="images/thumb_brochure_singlepage_front.jpg" width="50" height="117" alt=" "></td>
    <td align="center"><input name=" 3" type="text" class="qty" id=" 2" maxlength="2"></td>
    <td align="center" class="count">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="100" class="" name="radio6">
Rs. 100 </td>
    <td align="center"><img src="images/thumb_brochure_singlepage_front.jpg" width="50" height="117" alt=" "></td>
    <td align="center"><input name=" 4" type="text" class="qty" id=" 3" maxlength="2"></td>
    <td align="center" class="count">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="125" class="" name="radio7">
Rs. 125 </td>
    <td align="center"><img src="images/thumb_brochure_singlepage_back.jpg" alt=" "></td>
    <td align="center"><input name=" 6" type="text" class="qty" id=" 4" maxlength="2"></td>
    <td align="center" class="count">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center">Total</td>
    <td align="center" class="countTotal">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
              </table>
</div>
```

**SCIRPT**

```
$('.sticker input.qty, .brochure input.qty').prop('disabled', true);

        var total;
        var price = 0;
        var qty; 
        var prPrice = 0;
        var i = 0;
        var prPricemain = 0;
$('.sticker input[type="checkbox"], .brochure input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {

        var val = $(this).attr('value');
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').prop('disabled', false);        
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').val('1');
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.count').text(val);



        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').on('keyup',function(){
            qty = $(this).val();
            prPrice = qty * val;
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.count').text(prPrice);

            })

        }
    else
    {

        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').prop('disabled', true);     
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').val('');

            $(this).closest('tr').find('.count').text('');

        }




        $(this).closest('table').find('.count').each(function() {

            prPricemain = parseInt($(this).html());
            prPricemain = prPricemain + prPrice


        });

            $(this).closest('table').find('.countTotal').text(prPricemain);

    })


$('.qty').keyup(function(e)
{
    if (/\D/g.test(this.value))
    {
        alert('Numbers Only')
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has to do this the following code

```
$(this).closest('table').find('.count').each(function () {

    prPricemain = parseInt($(this).html());
    prPricemain = prPricemain + prPrice


});
```

**$(this).html()** is blank and therefore will return NaN.

I've changed the code to the following

```
prPricemain = 0;
$(this).closest('table').find('.count').each(function () {

    if ($.trim($(this).text()) && !isNaN($(this).text())) {
        prPrice = parseInt($(this).html());
        prPricemain = prPricemain + prPrice
    }

});
```

The reason for the change is not only were you getting the NaN for the total but your total would have continued to calculate up and never back down.

[My jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dklingman/UkEGa/)

**UPDATE**

In that case create a custome event to trigger when you want the calculation performed.

```
$('.sticker input[type="checkbox"], .brochure input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

        var val = $(this).attr('value');
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').val('1');
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.count').text(val);



        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').on('keyup', function () {

            qty = $(this).val();
            prPrice = qty * val;
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.count').text(prPrice);
            //Call the calculation event
            $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('calculateTotal');
        })

    } else {

        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').prop('disabled', true);
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').val('');

        $(this).closest('tr').find('.count').text('');

    }

    //Call the calculation event
    $(this).trigger('calculateTotal');
}).on('calculateTotal', function (e) {
    prPricemain = 0;
    $(this).closest('table').find('.count').each(function () {

        if ($.trim($(this).text()) && !isNaN($(this).text())) {
            prPrice = parseInt($(this).html());
            prPricemain = prPricemain + prPrice
        }

    });

    $(this).closest('table').find('.countTotal').text(prPricemain);
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dklingman/UkEGa/2/)

Comment: thanks for help... Ok i got it .. but what if I update quantity.. amount should be also change when I change quantity

Answer (score 2):

use this 
**Html**

```
<div class="brochure"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" >
  <tr>
    <td width="21%" align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="50" class="" name="radio"> 
    Rs. 50 </td>
    <td width="29%" align="center"><img src="images/thumb_brochure_singlepage_back.jpg" alt=" "></td>
    <td width="10%" align="center"><label for=" "></label>
      <input name=" 2" type="text" class="qty" id=" " maxlength="2"></td>
    <td width="40%" align="center" class="count">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="75" class="" name="radio5">
Rs. 75 </td>
    <td align="center"><img src="images/thumb_brochure_singlepage_front.jpg" width="50" height="117" alt=" "></td>
    <td align="center"><input name=" 3" type="text" class="qty" id=" 2" maxlength="2"></td>
    <td align="center" class="count">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="100" class="" name="radio6">
Rs. 100 </td>
    <td align="center"><img src="images/thumb_brochure_singlepage_front.jpg" width="50" height="117" alt=" "></td>
    <td align="center"><input name=" 4" type="text" class="qty" id=" 3" maxlength="2"></td>
    <td align="center" class="count">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="125" class="" name="radio7">
Rs. 125 </td>
    <td align="center"><img src="images/thumb_brochure_singlepage_back.jpg" alt=" "></td>
    <td align="center"><input name=" 6" type="text" class="qty" id=" 4" maxlength="2"></td>
    <td align="center" class="count">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center">Total</td>
    <td align="center" class="countTotal">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
              </table>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.sticker input.qty, .brochure input.qty').prop('disabled', true);

        var total;
        var price = 0;
        var qty; 
        var prPrice = 0;
        var i = 0;
        var prPricemain = 0;
$('.sticker input[type="checkbox"], .brochure input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {

        var val = $(this).attr('value');
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').prop('disabled', false);        
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').val('1');
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.count').text(val);



        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').on('keyup',function(){
            qty = $(this).val();
            prPrice = qty * val;
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.count').text(prPrice);

            })

        }
    else
    {

        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').prop('disabled', true);     
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').val('');

            $(this).closest('tr').find('.count').text('');

        }


         prPrice = 0;

        $(this).closest('table').find('.count').each(function() {

            prPricemain = parseInt($(this).html());

            if($(this).html()=="&nbsp;")
            {
            prPricemain=0;
            }else
            {

            prPrice = prPrice + prPricemain
            }


        });

            $(this).closest('table').find('.countTotal').text(prPrice);

    })


$('.qty').keyup(function(e)
{
    if (/\D/g.test(this.value))
    {
        alert('Numbers Only')
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    }});
$('.qty').blur(function(e)
{
prPrice=0;
    $(this).closest('table').find('.count').each(function() {

            prPricemain = parseInt($(this).html());

            if($(this).html()=="&nbsp;")
            {
            prPricemain=0;
            }else
            {

            prPrice = prPrice + prPricemain
            }


        });
        $(this).closest('table').find('.countTotal').text(prPrice);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UmcvP/1/